# Extracting a tar ball fails with "Cannot open: Not a directory"

Tags: tar, decompression

I am trying to extract an tarball, I keep getting this error

```
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/bp101wx1_n/bp101wx1_n.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/hsd070idw1/hsd070idw1.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/nt35582/nt35582.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/r63311_fhd_dsi_vdo_sharp/r63311_fhd_dsi_vdo_sharp.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/otm9608_wvga_dsi_cmd/otm9608_wvga_dsi_cmd.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/lg4571/lg4571.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/hx8363b_wvga_dsi_cmd/hx8363b_wvga_dsi_cmd.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/lg4573b_wvga_dsi_vdo_lh430mv1/lg4573b_wvga_dsi_vdo_lh430mv1.c: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The original file was a .zip file that contained a .tar.gz file, so I first used `unzip` then I used pigz with the -d option to create the tar file.

I extracted the tar file using tar with xf option.

Extracting the tar.gz using the tar xzf also doesn't work :/

Using 7za I get

```
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/bm8578/bm8578.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/nt35565_qhd_dsi_cmd/nt35565_qhd_dsi_cmd.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/spfd5461a/spfd5461a.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/bp101wx1_n/bp101wx1_n.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/hsd070idw1/hsd070idw1.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/nt35582/nt35582.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/r63311_fhd_dsi_vdo_sharp/r63311_fhd_dsi_vdo_sharp.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/otm9608_wvga_dsi_cmd/otm9608_wvga_dsi_cmd.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/lg4571/lg4571.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/hx8363b_wvga_dsi_cmd/hx8363b_wvga_dsi_cmd.c
can not open output file mediatek/custom/common/lk/lcm/lg4573b_wvga_dsi_vdo_lh430mv1/lg4573b_wvga_dsi_vdo_lh430mv1.c

Sub items Errors: 3869
```

The tar file is 3.8 GB if that matters

Comment: The file might be corrupted, use a checksum or similar to verify.

Comment: I'm sure it's corrupted, check with `gzip -t` the file. It will tell, also you might to know the bytes count if they don't fit with the servers.

Comment: The file is not corrupted, it extracts in Windows using WinRaR,(7zip doesn't extract it).

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](/q/25347) you can do `tar -xvzf location.tar.gz`. Try that

Comment: Doesn't work, tried it

Comment: And it's a tar.gz not tar?

Comment: yes, tried with the tar.gz too

Comment: Just a note that the order of the options is importatnt. `tar -xvfz` will throw a `cannot open: no such file or directory` but `tar -xvzf` will work.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the name of the directory you are extracting is the same as the file you are extracting, try to rename the archive file before extracting.

It worked for me when I had a similar problem.